# Is it possible to use the letter keys to access programs on Windows 8.1 Metro, like in XP?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-xp, shortcut

For those who remember (or still use) Windows XP, you might remember that you could launch the start bar with your Windows key on your keyboard and then hit the letter of the program/folder/file you wanted and as long as there wasn't another program/folder/file on the start bar starting with the same letter, it'd launch right away.
e.g. If you wanted to open excel, you'd hit the windows key and press the letter "e" and excel would launch.

So, for those who do remember that feature, I'm wondering, is there any way to get that functionality back in Windows 8.1? Right now, what happens is that when you hit the windows key, Metro pops up (which is fine) but if you type "e", for example, windows will automatically start searching instead of just launching Excel (or whatever letter you've typed).

I'd rather keep the interface as it is and, if possible, prefer not to install any 3rd party software (unless there's no other go). My preference is to be able to utilize the OS to get that option (if available), even if that includes going through regedit.

Just a note, I am already aware that 8.1 and XP are completely different architectures and I also realize that automatic searching does have its benefits but I prefer that specific XP functionality so it'd be great if I could get it back in 8.1.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Comment: Windows-X, R will bring up the Run dialog.  Or Windows-X, C will bring up a command line window; Windows-X, A if you want an admin window.

Comment: Thanks Harry but I don't understand how this answers what I asked. How would this help me launch specific programs on my metro screen? 
If you're suggesting that I can launch the programs from both the the run dialog box and CMD, then that doesn't work because I'd have to type in the name of the entire program plus the extension in order to get it to launch, 
I don't see how that would be faster/easier than just typing in the metro search box,
I'm trying to launch apps with the use of two keys (the windows key and whatever letter the program starts with, again, like you could do in XP)...

Comment: ... BTW, you don't have to type Windows+X, R (although, you can). You can bypass the admin menu and get directly to the run dialog by typing Windows+R.

Anyway, if I've misunderstood, your clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: So it does, I didn't know that one.  OK, I see what you mean now.  I have a vague feeling that Windows 10 does this a bit better, if I remember I'll check when I get home tonight.

Comment: No, Windows 10 seems to be behaving more like Windows 8 than like Windows 7/Vista/XP.  It does sometimes find certain applications, e.g., "gp" is sometimes enough for it to jump to "Edit Group Policy" but that isn't consistent either.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I've found that Windows 7 also has the same search function as 8 (i.e., when you press the windows key and start typing, it doesn't hi-light the program corresponding to the letter on the menu but starts searching for all programs/folders/files on your system that match the string that you've entered. Anyway, appreciate you looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the exact thing that I'm looking for but I've found somewhat of a workaround. You can create global keyboard shortcuts and thereby circumvent the metro/start screen altogether.

To do so, create a shortcut of the program/folder/file you want to easily access (the shortcut can be placed anywhere). Then, go to the properties of the shortcut and go to the shortcut tab where you can enter a global shortcut key (about half way down the box).

Of course, there are limitations to this because there are only a few keys (key combinations) free that you can use globally whereas with the XP method I was looking for, you could essentially have up to 36 different items you can access with just two keystrokes (26 letters, 10 numbers - not sure if other characters worked).

If anyone has figured out the XP method, though, that would be great.